# After ItemClickListener call methot

Tags: java, android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

I need to call the `createRandomList()` method at the end of `gridView.setOnItemClickListener`, 
but when I make this `gridView`, the `imageList` doesn't update.

If I call it in `textTT.setOnClickListener` it works. But I need it to work after `gridView.setOnItemClickListener`.

I mean that after `gridView.setOnItemClickListener`, the method `createRandomList()` should automatically be called again.

```
public class FragmentTrainingTest extends Fragment {

    Context context;
    TextView textTT;
    ArrayList<kayitSinifi> kelimeList = new ArrayList<>();
    int rand,position;
    Random r = new Random();
    MediaPlayer noVoice,yesVoice;
    ArrayList<kayitSinifi> randomList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    gridAdapter adapter;
    boolean ilkKez = true;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training_test, container, false);
        noVoice = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.glitchinthematrix);
        yesVoice= MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.fillingyourinbox);
        final GridView gridView = inflate.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        textTT= inflate.findViewById(R.id.txtTrainingTest);
        createRandomList();ilkKez = false;
        adapter = new gridAdapter(context,randomList,imageList);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        textTT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createRandomList(); gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });


        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("tester","Item clicked");
                 if(position == rand){
                     yesVoice.start();
                     imageList.set(rand,R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
                 } else {
                     noVoice.start();
                     imageList.set(position,R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);
                     imageList.set(rand,R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
                 }
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                //  createRandomList(); // please focus here
          }
        });

       return inflate;
    } //end of onCreateView

    private void createRandomList() {

        ArrayList<Integer> randomNumber = new ArrayList<>();
          // if (ilkKez) {} else try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        for (int i=0; randomList.size()>0;i++) randomList.remove(0);
        for (int i=0; imageList.size()>0;i++) imageList.remove(0);
        for (int i = 0; i< 6; i++) {
            do {
                rand = r.nextInt(kelimeList.size());
            }
            while(randomNumber.contains(rand));
            randomNumber.add(rand);
            randomList.add(kelimeList.get(rand));
            imageList.add(R.drawable.ic_fingerprint_black_24dp);
        }
        rand = r.nextInt(5); // 6 sayi belirlendi bu ise esas oglan
        textTT.setText(randomList.get(rand).anaDil);
        textTT.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        context=activity;
        dbaseHelper db = new dbaseHelper(context);
        kelimeList=db.dbList2();
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to make your question more readable. You should try to come up with a minimal code sample that exhibits your problem. Few people are ready to read through a wad of code like that.

Answer (score 0):

Place `createRandomList()` in front of `gridView.setAdapter(adapter);`

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("tester","Item clicked");
             if(position == rand){
                 yesVoice.start();
                 imageList.set(rand,R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
             } else {
                 noVoice.start();
                 imageList.set(position,R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);
                 imageList.set(rand,R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
             }
            createRandomList();
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Yes this works but problem is , there are 2 list for gridview, first randdomList updateed but sechond imageList doesn't updated ( this is my  problem)

Comment: actually I need this 
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter); 
                createRandomList();
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
first doesnt update